# OnAuthorizationAsync not being called when creating custom AuthorizeFilter that inherits from AuthorizeFilter

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I've created a custom authorize filter which looks like this:

```
public class BearerTokenAuthorizeFilter : AuthorizeFilter
{        
    public override async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        await base.OnAuthorizationAsync(context);
        if (context.Result is ChallengeResult)
        {
            // Then return a problem detail
            ObjectResult result = new ObjectResult(new ProblemDetails
            {
                Type = ProblemDetailsTypes.Unauthorized,
                Title = ReasonPhrases.GetReasonPhrase(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized),
                Status = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized,
                Detail = ProblemDetailsDescriptions.Unauthorized
            });
            result.ContentTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue(new Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringSegment("application/problem+json")));
            
            context.Result = result;
            await context.HttpContext.ChallengeAsync();
        }
        else if (context.Result is ForbidResult)
        {
            context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden);
            await context.HttpContext.ForbidAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I am registering this filter like this:

```
services.AddMvcCore(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<BearerTokenAuthorizeFilter>();
});
```

I have set the default authentication to be 'Bearer':

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

I have added `Authorize` attribute on the controller. Whenever I send an unauthorized request to the endpoint my custom filter is never called and I have no idea why? My goal is to return problem details if the request is unauthorized to provide a little bit more information to the consumer than just the status code. Why is my filter not being called?

Comment: Please check the [Middleware order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#middleware-order) in the Configure method in Startup.cs file, make sure you have added the UseAuthentication and UseAuthentication middleware, code like this: `app.UseAuthentication();app.UseAuthorization();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up implementing my own `IControllerModelConvention` class which looks like this:

```
public class BearerTokenAuthorizeConvention : IControllerModelConvention
{
    private AuthorizationPolicy _policy;

    public BearerTokenAuthorizeConvention(AuthorizationPolicy policy)
    {
        _policy = policy;
    }        
    public void Apply(ControllerModel controller)
    {
        if (controller.Filters.OfType<BearerTokenAuthorizeFilter>().FirstOrDefault() == null)
        {
            //default policy only used when there is no authorize filter in the controller
            controller.Filters.Add(new BearerTokenAuthorizeFilter(_policy));
        }
    }
}
```

This will be executed once per controller. I then registered this convention like this:

```
// Configure application filters and conventions
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
{
    AuthorizationPolicy defaultPolicy = new AuthorizationOptions().DefaultPolicy;
    options.Conventions.Add(new BearerTokenAuthorizeConvention(defaultPolicy));
});
```

At this point every controller I have will be tagged with this custom filter which will call base implementation of `AuthorizeFilter`. The reason why I wanted to derive from `AuthorizeFilter` was because I wanted to call the default implementation of `Authorize` and then handle failed response on my own. I thought I could accomplish this very functionality and somehow still be able to only use `Authorize` attribute. This doesn't seem to be possible. Unless it is an I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Try implement `IAuthorizationFilter` or `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter` instead of `AuthorizeFilter`. It work for me. Also I noticed that `GetFilter(..)` method returns `AuthorizeFilter` instance directly in `AuthorizationApplicationModelProvider` when filter class implements `AuthorizeFilter`. But when filter implements `IAuthorizationFilter` or `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter` this method being not called I think that is issue in ASP NET

Comment: I think the problem was, that I tagged controllers with `Authorize` attribute and not with `BearerTokenAuthorize`. So my custom filter was never called.